# Determine truth value

Tags: general-topology

If $ x \in \bigcup\{A:A \in \mathscr{A}\} $, then $x \in A$ for some $A \in \mathscr{A}$. $\mathscr{A}$ is a nonempty collection of sets and I have to determine the truth value of the above statement. I know about truth tables. $p\text{ and }q$ is true if both $p$ and $q$ are true, stuff like that. I just don't know how to start to show the truth value of the statement. How do you make a table for this?

Comment: To get the curly braces to display, you need to use `\{` and `\}`.

Comment: Oh ok thank you. I didn't even notice that

Comment: Is this not the naive definition of union?

Comment: @copper.hat: Indeed. And essentially the same as the formal definition used in the union axiom of $\mathsf{ZF}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t make a truth table: this is just a fancy way of asking you to determine whether the statement is true or false. In this case it’s true by definition: that’s the definition of the union of a collection of sets. That union can be written in several ways:

$$\bigcup\{A:A\in\mathscr{A}\}=\bigcup_{A\in\mathscr{A}}A=\bigcup\mathscr{A}\;,$$

for instance.

Comment: Well how do you do that? How do you show that its true or false? That's the thing I don't get how to do. I'm looking throughout my book but don't see it.

Comment: @Ruth: It’s true by definition: that’s the definition of the union of a collection of sets.

Comment: Oh yes I saw that. So just by the definition I can say its true? So if I had another question that had the same information but instead it said for all it would be false right because the definition said only for some?

Comment: @Ruth: That’s correct (unless, of course, $\mathscr{A}$ has only one member, in which case being in at least one is the same as being in all). In fact the set of $x$ such that $x\in A$ for all $A\in\mathscr{A}$ also has a name; what is it?

Comment: It would be the intersection

Comment: @Ruth: That’s right, and again that’s by definition.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Ruth: You’re very welcome. I added to the answer a little more information about notation that you might find useful at some point.